# Android ndk - set maximum number of simultainous jobs?

Tags: android, makefile, cygwin, android-ndk

I have the same problem as this one: [Android ndk build mysteriously failing under cygwin with "Error 126"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256963/android-ndk-build-mysteriously-failing-under-cygwin-with-error-126)

Occassionaly I get that error too. The solution suggests adding "-j 1" when you do make.. but how does that translate into when you use the ndk-build script? 
Is it simply "ndk-build -j 1"?

Comment: I have, but I cannot see if there is any difference. It dosn't complain about the flag or anything but I'm not sure if it has gone through

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to edit `ndk-build` script itself, and pass `-j1` to `$GNUMAKE`.

You will end up with something like this:

```
$GNUMAKE -j1 -f $PROGDIR/build/core/build-local.mk "$@"
```