# GNU Make Error 126, C:\Program is a directory

Tags: permissions, makefile, gnu-make

GNU make gives me a strange error message, which I do not understand.

```
gao@L8470-130213 ~
$ make
echo Test
C:\Program: C:\Program: is a directory
make: *** [test] Error 126
```

This is what I thought of verifying:

```
gao@L8470-130213 ~
$ less makefile
test:
        echo Test

gao@L8470-130213 ~
$ which make
/c/Programx86/GnuWin32/bin/make
gao@L8470-130213 ~
$ /c/Progra~2/GnuWin32/bin/make.exe test
echo Test
C:\Program: C:\Program: is a directory
make: *** [test] Error 126
gao@L8470-130213 ~
$ make --version
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-pc-mingw32
```

It feels like some other program is trying to run at the end, and that its path includes some spaces. In that case, what program could it be, and how can I prevent it from running?

I have seen [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5256963/android-ndk-build-mysteriously-failing-under-cygwin-with-error-126) and tried to disable my antivirus, which did not help.
I have also looked into permissions, but I am not sure if `makefile` needs execution rights. I can't seem to be able to change that anyway (running in bash on windows. `makefile` is not read-only when I check in explorer):

```
gao@L8470-130213 ~
$ ls -l makefile
-rw-r--r--    1 gao      Administ       21 Apr 15 14:53 makefile
gao@L8470-130213 ~
$ chmod +x makefile
gao@L8470-130213 ~
$ ls -l makefile
-rw-r--r--    1 gao      Administ       21 Apr 15 14:53 makefile
```

What is going on with `make`, what can I do?

Comment: It's not "some other program" that's trying to run, it's the `echo` command.  Make prints the command to be run, `echo test`, but you never see the output (`test`) so that means it failed trying to find the `echo` program.  Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with the vagaries of running GNU make on Windows: there are lots of different options.  One possibility would be to get a newer version of GNU make; 3.81 is very old.  3.82 is now available and might work better for you.

Comment: That's odd, `echo $PATH` from the same bash terminal works... but I see that `echo` does not output when called from the `makefile`.

Comment: 3.81 is what followed with GnuWin32 when I downloaded and installed it a couple of weeks ago. I'll try 3.82, but I think your theory about echo is more likely.

Comment: You are correct. Somehow `echo` works from directly within the bash, but not via `make`. Gnuwin32 does not include any `echo.exe`, but if I add to my `PATH` a location where there *is* an `echo.exe`, `make` is happy. I'd be glad to accept your answer, if you want to write it as such.

Comment: "Gnuwin32 does not include any `echo.exe`" -> this is not true. I failed to install it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not "some other program" that's trying to run, it's the `echo` command. Make prints the command to be run, `echo test`, but you never see the output (`test`) so that means it failed trying to find the echo program. Unfortunately I'm not very familiar with the vagaries of running GNU make on Windows: there are lots of different options. One possibility would be to get a newer version of GNU make; 3.81 is very old. 3.82 is now available and might work better for you.

Good info you added above about your environment re: using bash; that wasn't clear from the original question and on Windows there are many different ways to do things.  You're using the mingw version of make; that version (as I understand it) does NOT use bash as the shell to run commands in: it's supposed to be used with native Windows environments which do not, certainly, have bash available.  I believe that the version of make you have is invoking commands directly, and/or using command.com.  Certainly not a UNIX shell like bash.

If you want to use bash you should set the `SHELL` make variable to the path of your bash.exe program.  If you're using a Cygwin environment you can use the GNU make that comes with Cygwin which behaves more like a traditional make + shell.

Otherwise you'll need to write your commands using Windows command.com statements.

Again, I don't use Windows so this is mostly hearsay.

PS. The makefile does not need to be executable.

Answer (score 1):

What is going on is that [make doesn't like file names or directory names with spaces in them,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838384/can-gnu-make-handle-filenames-with-spaces) such as `Program Files`. Neither do most of the utilities that makefiles typically rely on, such as the shell to execute commands with.

I create a [junction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_junction_point) from `Program Files` to `ProgramFiles` and use the latter whenever I encounter cases like this.

Comment: I do already have junctions (Program and Programx86). Although I had the same feeling when I first saw `C:\Program`, this was not the problem. The problem was that make could not find echo.exe. See the comments under the question, as well as MadScientist's answer.

Comment: Ah ... then one of your junction names is confusing :)

Comment: I do think it tried to display "program files" and failed, but I don't know why it would even try.